# Can not login to drupal site using Wamp 2.5

Tags: authentication, drupal-7, wamp, wampserver

I purchase a new Windows 8 laptop for Drupal development.  I have installed Wamp 2.5 on it and I am moving / copying the sites from the old W7 development machine to thew W8 machine.

I moved the code and the /files directory and user mysql command line to restore the data.  I then setup the local link in the host file as

```
127.0.0.1       dev.local
```

and setup the httpd.conf as

```
#
#   dev.local
#
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName dev.local
    DocumentRoot "C:\Sites\www\dev"
    <Directory "C:\Sites\www\dev">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The dev site come up and it public facing side (role = anonymous) works find.  When I try to login using dev.local/user - the user login page appears.

But when I enter my user name and password and then press enter, I see the message "waiting on dev.local" appear and disappear in the bottom left corner of the page, but drupal does not log me in.  Also,

- No error message is displayed. If I enter in a invalid user name the
  same thing occurs - and no error message is displayed
- And this is happening on three different development web sites on
  this machine.
- I have no problems logging into these three sites on the W7 machine.
- And I have already tried to reset the user 1 password using drush.
  While the drush command appears to work, but I can not login.
- I looked in the user table, and all of the users are there.
- I cleared the watchdog table and tried to login. No messages are
  being posted to the watchdog table when I try to login.

  Does anyone have any idea what I need to do so that I can login in my sites?

Comment: What error are you seeing in the logs? i.e. PHP, Apache, MySQL, Is there a seperate drupal log?

Answer (score 1):

Verify your settings as follow.

1. Click on Wamp icon and open Apache/httpd.conf and search "rewrite_module". Remove # modules/mod_rewrite.so and save it

   `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`
   Restart the apache service.
2. Make sure that your drupal root have `.htaccess` file. This file may be hidden. If you dont find this file then copy it from source and paste it.

If all above fails then try to disable clean url using drush commands

```
drush vset clean_url 0
```